# Why won't George come?

Tags: knowledge

"Oh boy, it's a boys-only party ! There'll be Jim, who never sleeps, and Jimmy, who's capable of anything. Charlie and Mike'll be there for sure, they're always so excited. And Nick... man, Nick just has that thing, you know, he's so fascinating! Sure, Andy can be a little cold (and let's not mention Bill...), Al is a little too loud sometimes -especially when he drinks too much with Big Boy Izzy-, but man, even Henry will be there, and we don't see him around much anymore ! Oh George, won't you come ?"

But George won't. Why ?

---

Hints :

> As visualnotsobasic suggests in the comments. All names here refer to historical figures. All are men, including George. All these men had the same occupation. The names given are nicknames of their actual names.

Comment: Taking the first letter from the 1st, 3rd, 4th and 6th lines makes "oh bc" (bc stands for because)

Comment: Is the question in any way related to historical figures?

Comment: @visualnotsobasic yes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is related to

> Physical units, and their historical namesakes

We have

Jim

> James Prescott **Joule** (full of energy, never sleeps)

Jimmy

> James **Watt** (has power to do anything?)

Charlie

> Charles Augustin de **Coulomb**

Mike

> Michael **Faraday**

Nick

> Nikola **Tesla**

Andy

> Anders **Celsius** (a little cold)

Bill

> William Thompson, Lord **Kelvin** (scale is often used for colder temperatures)

Al

> Alexander Graham **Bel**l (as in decibel), who can be loud. (First suggestion: Alessandro **Volt**a)

Izzy

> Isaac **Newton**

Henry

> Heinrich **Hertz** (who is seen less frequently). (Prev answer: Unit of inductance, named after Joseph **Henry**, but he is known as Joe to the gang).

As to why George won't come

> Georg **Ohm** is putting up too much...

.

> Resistance

Comment: Congratulations, this is in essence the right answer ! I feel like maybe you haven't used all the descriptions to get the correct men each time. For example (rot13)Urael vf Uregm orpnhfr "jr qba'g frr uvz nebhaq zhpu nalzber" ersref gb gur serdhrapl ng juvpu gur tnat frrf uvz. 
Al is wrong too.

Comment: I have had a second go at Al, and switched the alternative for Henry to be the answer

Comment: Everything is correct now !

Comment: Thanks! Alternative punchline: George decided he'd rather... (rot13)fgnl ng Buz

Comment: (rot13)Buz-ltbfu...

Answer (score 3):

Because George is

> either [George Eliot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Eliot), a.k.a. Mary Ann Evans,
> or [George Sand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Sand), a.k.a. Amantine Lucile Aurore Dupin. 
> Both were (female) authors (George Eliot wrote *Silas Marner*)
> who used “George” as a pseudonym.

Comment: Intriguing idea, but it seems like this needs some explanation of (1) who all the others are, and (2) why "our" George should be either of those.

Comment: Nice answer I actually thought of when writing this puzzle, but not the one I was expecting. I can confirm "our" George is indeed a man. Like Gareth says, all other names are important (although it's not necessary to "get" all of them to find why George won't come)